# Disable Bash autocompletion for a specific command only

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Is it possible to disable Bash's autocompletion for a specific command only?

Use case: For obvious reasons, I would like to disable autocompletion for the `rm` command when I'm root. It would also be a terrible pain if I disabled autocompletion altogether, so I'd like to remove it for `rm` only.

Can this be done at all, preferably without hacking `/etc/bash_completion` and friends?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this easily by setting `rm`'s completion to an empty wordlist.

```
complete -W "" rm
```

Set it in /root/.bashrc if you only want it to apply to root.

Comment: Works just as advertised. Thank you very much!

Comment: `complete -C : rm` and `complete rm` work too:)